# local class with classmethod does not work but imported version works

Tags: python, import

I'm creating a manager - member pair of classes, Mgr, Mem respectively.  The Mgr class sets a reference to itself, by invoking Mem.set_manager(self) during **init**.  While this is successful if both classes are imported, it fails in Mem's self-test execution.  My question - what gives here?  My current workaround - explicitly executing the class method after the Mgr creation (Mem.set_mgr(mgr1)) is shown.

Output from running test_class_set_mem.py standalone:

```
set_mgr called
mgr is NOT set
Setting explicitly from class
set_mgr called
mgr is set
```

code:test_class_set_mgr.py

```
# test_class_set_mgr.py
# Setting class variable
from test_class_set_mem import Mem

class Mgr:
    def __init__(self):
        Mem.set_mgr(self)    # Set communication link
```

code: test_class_set_mem.py

```
# test_class_set_mem.py
# Setting class variable

class Mem:
    mgr = None      # Required mgr reference
    @classmethod
    def set_mgr(cls, mgr):
        cls.mgr = mgr
        print("set_mgr called")
    
    def __init__(self):
        if Mem.mgr is None:
            print("mgr is NOT set")
        else:
            print("mgr is set")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from test_class_set_mgr import Mgr
    
    mgr1 = Mgr()    # set_mgr called from __init__
    mem1 = Mem()
    print("Setting explicitly from class")
    Mem.set_mgr(mgr1)
    mem2 = Mem()
```

Code, importing both the classes works:

```
# test_class_set3.py
# Setting class variable

from test_class_set_mem import Mem            
from test_class_set_mgr import Mgr

mgr1 = Mgr()
mem1 = Mem()
```

Output from running test_class_set3.py

```
set_mgr called
mgr is set
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to circular imports. The file `test_class_set_mgr.py` imports `Mem` from `test_class_set_mem` and `test_class_set_mem.py` imports `Mgr` from `test_class_set_mgr`.

As a result, when you self-execute `test_class_set_mem.py`, the code of the `Mem` class is run twice with different module names. First, it is executed as an object in the `__main__` module. Then, when the line

```
from test_class_set_mem import Mem
```

is reached it is executed again, as a part of the `test_class_set_mem`
module. In effect, the `Mem` class used to instantiate the `Mgr` class is not the same as the one used to create an instance of the `Mem` class. You can check it by comparing ids of `Mem` classes used by `Mgr.__init__()`  and `Mem.__init__()`:

test_class_set_mgr.py:

```
# test_class_set_mgr.py
# Setting class variable
from test_class_set_mem import Mem

class Mgr:

    def __init__(self):
        print(f"In Mgr.__init__(). Mem class id:  {id(Mgr)}")
        Mem.set_mgr(self)    # Set communication link
```

test_class_set_mem.py:

```
# test_class_set_mem.py
# Setting class variable

class Mem:

    mgr = None      # Required mgr reference
    @classmethod
    def set_mgr(cls, mgr):
        cls.mgr = mgr
        print("set_mgr called")
    
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"In Mem.__init__(). Member class id: {id(self.__class__)}")
        if Mem.mgr is None:
            print("mgr is NOT set")
        else:
            print("mgr is set")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from test_class_set_mgr import Mgr
    

    mgr1 = Mgr()    # set_mgr called from __init__
    mem1 = Mem()
```

Output:

```
In Mgr.__init__(). Mem class id:  140527440788784
set_mgr called
In Mem.__init__(). Mem class id: 140527440785216
mgr is NOT set
```

The upshot is that the code `mgr1 = Mgr()` sets the `mgr` attribute of one `Mem` class, but `mem1 = Mem()` uses a different `Mem` class, which does not have this attribute set.